# CSS hover only works in the bottom half

Tags: html, css, button, hover, href

I changed the position of the div section to relative from absolute. After i made the change when i move the cursor to the top of the div, only the bottom half can be clicked. The hover images changes only when i move the cursor on the bottom half.

```
.vote2 {
display: block;
box-sizing: border-box;
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
float: left;
position: relative;
top: -920px;
left: 800px;
border-style: solid;
border-color: Black;


}

a div.vote2:hover {
width: 100px; 
border-style: solid;
border-color: Black;
background: url('http://localhost/Images/x.jpg');
display:block;

}

.wrapper{
width: 1095px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
height:600px;   
 }
```

The html part

```
  <div class="wrapper">
     <a href=" http://localhost/Login.php"><div class="vote2"></div></a> 
  </div>
```

Comment: create fiddle for the same...

Comment: any reason behind this `top: -920px;
left: 800px;`

Comment: works fine if you remove it http://jsfiddle.net/29katdgk/

Comment: if the top is not negative it goes to the bottom of the page don't know the reason

Comment: After I add the google pie chart i had to change all the other elements to  negative